# Prove the differential of $f$ at $x_1$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

$f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is homogenic from degree $p$ for every $t>0$ and $f$ is $C^{1}$
$$f(tx)=t^{p}f(x)$$
Prove $\frac{df}{dx_1}$ is homogenic from degree p-1

I've tried to use the chain rule with $\gamma(x)=x$

Comment: Hint: What happens if you differentiate the defining equation with respect to the parameter $t$?

Comment: i thought about it but it felt too simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$t\frac {\partial } {\partial x_1} f(tx)=t^{p} \frac {\partial } {\partial x_1} f(x)$ by differentiation w.r.t. $x_1$. Just divide by $t$.